# How to call select_linked_pick from script?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to call select_linked_pick from my script so that it behaves as if you had pressed L with the cursor hovering over part of a mesh. Problem is when I try to call it from script it doesn't appear that anything happens.

```
def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked_pick()
```

There is no output in the console, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am using this to linked select :   
bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked_pick(deselect=False, delimit={'SEAM'}, index=vertex.index)   . Index value depends on that:
if it is a vertex : just index of it.
if it is an edge:  total vertex number + index of edge.
if it is a face: total vertex number + total edge number + index of face

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still don't understand though; Running your code as is returns an error: name 'vertex' is undefined.

How do I find the index of the vertex under the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve this issue by simply using different operators to get the same result:

```
    loc = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y

    bpy.ops.view3d.select(location=loc)
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked()
```

Found from [this answer by CoDEmanX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7873/get-edge-vertex-face-from-mouse-position).

Seemed a lot simpler in the end than trying to retrieve the right indexes for everything to use select_linked_pick...

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution, I think that will help me a lot also, thank you:)

Comment: +1, and just remember that in order to have `event`, you need to create an `invoke` wrapper and e.g. assign the event or a part of it to a object var(s) which will then be passed as `self` to `execute` (seems simple if you know it, but I spent an hour trying to figure it out :)