# How to run this operator?

Tags: python

I've found a script that I want to test and use from a thread around, which was marked as "SOLVED" with this script. However, I can't get how this script is used:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
     """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.object is not None and
            context.object.type == 'MESH' and
            context.object.data.is_editmode)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        me = context.object.data
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        verts_sel = [v.select for v in bm.verts]
        edges_sel = [e.select for e in bm.edges]
        faces_sel = [f.select for f in bm.faces]

        loc = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
        try:
            geom = bm.select_history[-1]
        except IndexError:
            geom = None

        ret = bpy.ops.view3d.select(extend=True, location=loc)
        if ret == {'PASS_THROUGH'}:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "no close-by geom")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        try:
            geom2 = bm.select_history[-1]
            print("geom2 sel 1st", geom2.select)
        except IndexError:
            geom2 = None

        if geom is None:
            geom = geom2

        if isinstance(geom, bmesh.types.BMVert):
            geom_sel = verts_sel
            bm_geom = bm.verts
        elif isinstance(geom, bmesh.types.BMEdge):
            geom_sel = edges_sel
            bm_geom = bm.edges
        elif isinstance(geom, bmesh.types.BMFace):
            geom_sel = faces_sel
            bm_geom = bm.faces

        for sel, g in zip(geom_sel, bm_geom):
            if sel != g.select:
                g.select_set(True)
                bm.select_history.remove(g)
                bm.select_flush_mode()
                break


        self.report({'INFO'}, repr(geom))
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The thread I am mention is here: [Get Edge / Vertex / Face from mouse position](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7873/get-edge-vertex-face-from-mouse-position) 
Please, if you can explain what I have to do with this code.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically if you don't define an interface for your operator, you can run your code and then press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and search it with the name of "simple object operator" in the box that appears. When you find it, simply click it and it will run.
[image]

Comment: Hello, I've tried this, 'Spacebar' on the context next to the script editor, however the operator is not present there.

Comment: Probably because the `poll` function doesn't show that to you. In fact, this function explains where are the conditions for the operator to be applicable . If you remove that part, the operator will be always applicable. I will update my answer with a screenshot anyway.

Comment: Your `poll` function is saying: "You can apply this operator if context.object is not None, if your object is a mesh and if you are in edit mode". In the image I uploaded I just removed this function, but it works perfectly even with that.